Why can not fetch newest data through `.collectAsState()` method?
issue
Can not fetch new data in .collectAsState() method, appeared in
Code
In LoadFoodItemInfo.kt
The method is invoked.
FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)

But after the above statement,
the output of
Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")

is
LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[]
where
the variable foodItemVOs is defined as follows.
val foodItemVOs by foodItemViewModel.data.collectAsState()

Why can not fetch newest data through collectAsState method in StateFlow ?
Here is my code.
In LoadFoodItemInfo.kt
@Composable
fun LoadFoodItemInfo(
    context:Context,
    foodItemViewModel: FoodItemViewModel = viewModel(),
    foodViewModel: FoodViewModel = viewModel(),
){
    val TAG = "tag_LoadFoodItemInfo"
    val selectedFoodItemVO by foodItemViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
    val foodItemVOs by foodItemViewModel.data.collectAsState()    
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))    
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, selectedFoodItemVO:${selectedFoodItemVO}")    
        val queriedFoodItemVOs = foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(selectedFoodItemVO)    
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:${queriedFoodItemVOs}")
        if(queriedFoodItemVOs.isEmpty()){                Toast.makeText(context,context.getString(R.string.load_food_item_info_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show()    
            return@LaunchedEffect    
        }    
// set all elem of the array into repo -- FoodItemRepository.    
        FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)            Toast.makeText(context,context.getString(R.string.load_food_item_info_successfully), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show()    
        Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")    
        UpdateSelectedFoodItemVOs(
            context = context,
            foodItemVOs = foodItemVOs,
            foodViewModel = foodViewModel,
        )
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
    }    
}

In FoodItemViewModel.kt
class FoodItemViewModel:ViewModel() {    
    private val repository = FoodItemRepository    
    val data: StateFlow<List<FoodItemVO>> = repository.datasFlow    
    ...
}

In FoodItemRepository.kt
object FoodItemRepository {
    val TAG = "tag_MealsOptionRepository"
    private val _datasFlow: MutableStateFlow<MutableList<FoodItemVO>> = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf())    
    val datasFlow = _datasFlow.asStateFlow()    
    ...    
    fun setDatas(newDatas: List<FoodItemVO>) {
        Log.e(TAG, "~".repeat(50))
            Log.e(TAG, "In setDatas method,newDatas:${newDatas}")
        _datasFlow.value = newDatas.toMutableList()    
        Log.e(TAG, "In setDatas method,_datasFlow.value:${_datasFlow.value}")    
        Log.e(TAG, "~".repeat(50))
    }
    ...
}

Here is the last part of content of Logcat when I executed the program.
2024-11-10 21:52:43.992 26480-26480 tag\_sendHttpRequest com.example.healthhelper E sendHttpRequest function was finished called.

2024-11-10 21:52:43.992 26480-26480 tag\_sendHttpRequest com.example.healthhelper E --------------------------------------------------

2024-11-10 21:52:43.993 26480-26480 tag\_LoadFoodItemInfo com.example.healthhelper E In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:\[FoodItemVO(diaryID=8, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=3, grams=100.0)\]

2024-11-10 21:52:43.993 26480-26480 tag\_MealsO...Repository com.example.healthhelper E ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

2024-11-10 21:52:43.995 26480-26480 tag\_MealsO...Repository com.example.healthhelper E In setDatas method,newDatas:\[FoodItemVO(diaryID=8, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=3, grams=100.0)\]

2024-11-10 21:52:43.995 26480-26480 tag\_MealsO...Repository com.example.healthhelper E In setDatas method,\_datasFlow.value:\[FoodItemVO(diaryID=8, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=3, grams=100.0)\]

2024-11-10 21:52:43.995 26480-26480 tag\_MealsO...Repository com.example.healthhelper E ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

2024-11-10 21:52:43.998 26480-26480 tag\_LoadFoodItemInfo com.example.healthhelper E LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:\[\]

2024-11-10 21:52:43.999 26480-26480 tag\_Update...oodItemVOs com.example.healthhelper E In UpdateSelectedFoodItemVOs function, foodItemVOs:\[\]

2024-11-10 21:52:44.000 26480-26480 tag\_Update...oodItemVOs com.example.healthhelper E In UpdateSelectedFoodItemVOs function, foodNames:\[\]

2024-11-10 21:52:44.000 26480-26480 tag\_Update...oodItemVOs com.example.healthhelper E In UpdateSelectedFoodItemVOs function, selectedFoodItemVOs:\[\]

Appreciation
Any reply or tips about this issue will be highly appreciated.
What did I try?

Find the details of issue through output on Logcat.

read the Jetpack Compose collectAsState() does not work with Flow combine() and try to understand the usage in this article.


What was I expected?
Fetch the newest data of repository at anytime (including, after updating value of StateFlow in repository.
P.S.
I follow MVVM design pattern.
The project location
The project is located at Github.
https://github.com/junshin4211/HealthHelper/blob/2b9fd8d89bd7a9bb3ee5387d8ebfc9f2e578fbbb/app
But notice that it is version controlled by Git, so other people not in this group may have no permission to access it.

1th Edit
preface
I take @tyg's comment to try to reproduce the minimal example. Also I reformat the code. And rearrange the description of this issue.
issue
same as above.
description
In LoadFoodItemInfo.kt
The method is invoked as follows.
FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)

But after execution of above statement,
the output of
Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")

is
LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[]

Logcat
Output of Logcat
Code
LoadFoodItemInfoTest1.kt
Here is definition of function LoadFoodItemInfoTest1.
@Composable
fun LoadFoodItemInfoTest1(
    context:Context,
    foodItemViewModel: FoodItemViewModel = viewModel(),
){
    val TAG = "tag_LoadFoodItemInfoTest1"

    val selectedFoodItemVO by foodItemViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
    val foodItemVOs by foodItemViewModel.data.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, selectedFoodItemVO:${selectedFoodItemVO}")
        val queriedFoodItemVOs =  foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(selectedFoodItemVO)
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:${queriedFoodItemVOs}")
        if(queriedFoodItemVOs.isEmpty()){
            return@LaunchedEffect
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"The statement is ready to execute FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs).")
        FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)
        Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
    }
}

FoodItemViewModel.kt
Here is part of code of definition of FoodItemViewModel class (which is a view model for FoodItemRepository object.
// some import statements

class FoodItemViewModel:ViewModel() {
    private val repository = FoodItemRepository
    val data: StateFlow<List<FoodItemVO>> = repository.datasFlow
    ...
    suspend fun selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(
        foodItemVO: FoodItemVO,
    ):List<FoodItemVO>{
        val url = DietDiaryUrl.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryIdUrl
        return try {
            val result = httpPost(url, gson.toJson(foodItemVO))
            val collectionType = object : TypeToken<List<FoodItemVO>>() {}.type
            gson.fromJson(result, collectionType) ?: emptyList()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Fetch Error", "Error fetching food from ${url}: ${e.message}", e)
            emptyList()
        }
    }
    ...

Here is some import statements in FoodItemViewModel.kt
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import com.example.healthhelper.dietary.gson.gson
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

where
DietDiaryUrl.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryIdUrl is defined in DietDiaryUrl.kt as follows.
val selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryIdUrl: String
        get() = "${serverUrl}/dietDiary/foodItem/selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId"

In FoodItemRepository.kt
The part of code of FoodItemRepository object is shown as follows.
// some import statements
object FoodItemRepository {
    val TAG = "tag_MealsOptionRepository"

    private val _datasFlow: MutableStateFlow<MutableList<FoodItemVO>> = MutableStateFlow(mutableListOf())
    val datasFlow: StateFlow<List<FoodItemVO>>
        get() = _datasFlow.asStateFlow()
    ...
    
    fun setDatas(newDatas:List<FoodItemVO>){
        Log.e(TAG,"~".repeat(50))
        Log.e(TAG,"In setDatas method,newDatas:${newDatas}")
        _datasFlow.value = newDatas.toMutableList()
        Log.e(TAG,"In setDatas method,_datasFlow.value:${_datasFlow.value}")
        Log.e(TAG,"~".repeat(50))
    }
  
    ...

Here is some import statements in FoodItemRepository.kt
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.StateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.asStateFlow


2th Edit
description
I change it from MutableStateFlow<MutableList<E>> to ``MutableStateFlow<List>` as shown below.
object FoodItemRepository {
    val TAG = "tag_MealsOptionRepository"

    private val _datasFlow: MutableStateFlow<List<FoodItemVO>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())
    val datasFlow: StateFlow<List<FoodItemVO>>
        get() = _datasFlow.asStateFlow()

But it does not work for me.
Output of Logcat
Output of Logcat

Your StateFlows contain MutableLists, that's not gonna work. Make sure the Lists are immutable. If you need further help you need to provide all relevant code so we can execute it ourselves. [edit] your question accordingly, providing a [mre]. Make sure all relevant parts are there, but also remove everything that is not necessary. Also, make sure your code is properly formatted. As it is there seems to be something wrong with your underlines, and you also do not need that many empty lines. That makes it hard to read your code, so please also fix that.

@tyg  thanks for reminding. I'll fix it.

@tyg I want to provide minimal reproducible example, but I don't have an idea how to do so, since the above code is one small part of the project which is hard and troublesome to split them out. (May spent lots of time and my team doesn't  have lots time to fix it. We have pressured on finishing developing app today.

@tyg About the sentence, Your StateFlows contain MutableLists, that's not gonna work I don't know why. Can you take patience to explain the reason. Thank you.

You can start by copying the above code into a new project and  improve it so that it executes. Then test if the issue you have in your original code also occurs there. If not, then compare both apps and add parts of your original code to the new project until the issue also occurs there. Now the code satisfies the "Reproducible" part of MRE. To also make it "Minimal", remove everything from the new project that isn't necessary to reproduce the issue and voilà, you have your **MRE// that you can use in your question.

A StateFlow only detects changes when they are set by the value property or via the update function. If the value is mutable (like your MutableList) it can change without the flow detecting it and the flow cannot inform its collectors of the changed value. The collectAsState won't trigger a recomposition and the UI won't update accordingly. Therefore you should only use immutable types in a StateFlow.

@tyg I place my minimal reproducible code in 1th Edit section,

@GeeksMathGeeks hi. I hope my answer below will help. A friendly reminder: people do not usually have time to read through convoluted lines, the easier the examples are, the better. The clearer you isolate the problem and the problematic code, the easier it will be for people to read and give you answers. Some may be averted by unnecessarily long lines of code and examples that do not constitute the main issue, e. g. the LOG statements and the imports

@tyg thank's for explaining.

@tyg but why does it work, even I change it from MutableStateFlow<MutableList<E>> to MutableStateFlow<List<E> as shown in 2th edition section.

This is getting out of hand. Instead of becoming minimal, you add even more code to the question. Everything you write someone else needs to read. And most of what's in your question is superfluous. This is a huge waste of time. Please remove everything that is not strictly necessary to demonstrate the issue. Stack Overflow keeps its own version history, so do not list all your previous attempts, only the latest version is needed. And there is still important information missing. This is far from a [mre]. Please try again.

From a quick glance at the problems you've mentioned, I noticed a couple of possible useful solutions.
If you want to observe a MutableList as a State in Compose, you have to use not just a simple State but a SnapshotStateList<T> [link] which can be obtained with a built-in
public fun <T> mutableStateListOf(): SnapshotStateList<T> 

Here is an example:
//Creating an instance of a MutableList that is observable and can be snapshot.


@Composable
fun Names() {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("user") }
    val names = remember { mutableStateListOf<String>() }

    Column {
        Row {
            BasicTextField(value = name, onValueChange = { name = it })
            Button(onClick = { names.add(name) }) { Text("Add") }
        }
        Text("Added names:")
        Column {
            for (addedName in names) {
                Text(addedName)
            }
        }
    }
}

As for the part in your post that said

read the Jetpack Compose collectAsState() does not work with Flow combine() and try to understand the usage in this article.

The .combine() method produces a cold flow, so there is a simple fix to turn it into a hot StateFlow that can be observed.
Here is a simple example:
    data class YourStateHolder(val first: String, val second : String)

    val firstFlow = flow { repeat(10){
        emit("firstFlow: $it")
        delay(500)
    } }

    val secondFlow = flow { repeat(10){
        emit("secondFlow: $it")
        delay(800)
    } }

    val yourState: StateFlow<YourStateHolder> = combine(
        firstFlow, secondFlow
    ) { first, second ->
        YourStateHolder(
            first = first, second = second
        )
    }.stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),
        YourStateHolder("initial_1", "initial_2")
    )

Hope that's helpful.

val selectedFoodItemVO by foodItemViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
The state vo returned by this line of code can be used directly in the UI view and will be automatically recognized and reorganized.
However, you used the selectedFoodItemVO state object in LaunchedEffect:
val queriedFoodItemVOs = foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(selectedFoodItemVO)
So: You need to write like this to execute the
foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId function when the selectedFoodItemVO state changes, because:
LaunchedEffect(Unit) will only be in
@Composable fun LoadFoodItemInfoTest1 is triggered for the first time.
Since the unit has no state, it will not be triggered subsequently. Therefore, you need to write like this:
@Composable
fun LoadFoodItemInfoTest1(
    context:Context,
    foodItemViewModel: FoodItemViewModel = viewModel(),
){
    val TAG = "tag_LoadFoodItemInfoTest1"

    val selectedFoodItemVO by foodItemViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
    val foodItemVOs by foodItemViewModel.data.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(selectedFoodItemVO) {
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, selectedFoodItemVO:${selectedFoodItemVO}")
        val queriedFoodItemVOs =  foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(selectedFoodItemVO)
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:${queriedFoodItemVOs}")
        if(queriedFoodItemVOs.isEmpty()){
            return@LaunchedEffect
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"The statement is ready to execute FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs).")
        FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)
        Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
    }
}


solution
Thank's to teacher, I understand two concepts and found a solution.
The collectionAsState of StateFlow or its related class of a variable (for example namely meal) will try to fetch new data when the meal (for example meal) is recomposed.
example
Here is example modified by teacher.
@Composable
fun LoadFoodItemInfo(
    context:Context,
    foodItemViewModel: FoodItemViewModel = viewModel(),
){
    val TAG = "tag_LoadFoodItemInfoTest1"

    val selectedFoodItemVO by foodItemViewModel.selectedData.collectAsState()
    val foodItemVOs by foodItemViewModel.data.collectAsState()

    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, selectedFoodItemVO:${selectedFoodItemVO}")
        val queriedFoodItemVOs =  foodItemViewModel.selectFoodItemByDiaryIdAndMealCategoryId(selectedFoodItemVO)
        Log.e(TAG,"In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:${queriedFoodItemVOs}")
        if(queriedFoodItemVOs.isEmpty()){
            return@LaunchedEffect
        }
        Log.e(TAG,"The statement is ready to execute FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs).")
        FoodItemRepository.setDatas(queriedFoodItemVOs)
        Log.e(TAG,"LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")
        Log.e(TAG,"-".repeat(50))
    }
    if(foodItemVOs.isNotEmpty()){
        Log.e(TAG,"Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:${foodItemVOs}")
    }
}

Output on Logcat
About this tag in above example,
2024-11-13 20:40:08.052  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]
2024-11-13 20:40:08.137  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]
2024-11-13 20:40:09.772  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]
2024-11-13 20:40:09.899  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  --------------------------------------------------
2024-11-13 20:40:09.900  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  In LoadFoodItemInfo function, selectedFoodItemVO:FoodItemVO(diaryID=0, foodID=2, mealCategoryID=2, grams=2.0)
2024-11-13 20:40:09.961  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  In LoadFoodItemInfo function, queriedFoodItemVOs:[]
2024-11-13 20:40:09.973  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]
2024-11-13 20:40:10.486  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]
2024-11-13 20:40:10.559  5804-5804  tag_LoadFo...mInfoTest1 com.example.healthhelper             E  Out of LaunchedEffect(Unit) block was called.foodItemVOs:[FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1001, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100245.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1002, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1003, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1004, mealCategoryID=2, grams=1.00234E8), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1005, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1006, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1007, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1008, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1009, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0), FoodItemVO(diaryID=9, foodID=1010, mealCategoryID=2, grams=100.0)]

